# Are there any non constant - convergent sequence with discrete metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent under euclidean metric. But not convergent with discrete metric.

Is there a non-constant convergent sequence with discrete metric ?

Comment: It need not be constant right from the start.

Comment: you mean that there is $N$ such that for each $n>N$ , sequence coverges ? That is it has a constant tail after some $N$ .

Comment: Yes. In a discrete space, a convergent sequence is _eventually_ constant. But of course it can behave arbitrarily at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

No, in discrete metric, every point is isolated – every singleton $\{x\}$ is open, and hence every sequence converging to $x$ must have a final segment contained in $\{x\}$. So it is eventually constant.

Answer (score 1):

Same as other answer, except note that "eventually constant" is not the same as "constant." So it's easy to find non-constant examples.

Comment: An example if possible ?

Comment: @AngeloMark Look at the sequence $0,1,1,1,\cdots$ meaning after the initial $0$ all terms are $1$. It converges to $1$ in discrete metric yet is not a constant sequence.